# 301 permanent redirect with script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My url structure is this.

```
domain/locale/villas/villa-name/summary
domain/locale/villas/villa-name/photos
domain/locale/villas/villa-name/location
ect

domain/locale/apartmens/villa-name/summary
domain/locale/apartmens/villa-name/photos
domain/locale/apartmens/villa-name/location
ect
```

I want to add 2 new params in in the url (db relationships already added), like this

```
domain/locale/italy/umbria/villas/villa-name/summary
```

How can i redirect 'old' url's to the new url structure? with a script (i can do this manualy in the routes file for each url but i have 2000 url's so this approach is not recommended)

Thanks..remco

Comment: nope...thats not possibly

Comment: is that because you are still using Mongrel, or because you are not using Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
redirect_to path_or_url, :status => :moved_permanently
```

Comment: ok...but how can i this with the correct url params...so the old url is redirect properly to the new url

Comment: You can directly redirects from the routes too.